# Modelar relación 1:1 por referencia en NoSQL (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Es la primera vez que trabajo con NoSQL y me surge un problema bastante tonto. Quiero guardar información sobre libros así que podría tener un documento así:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("52f602d787945c344bb4bda5"),
  titulo: "Los pilares de la Tierra",
  autor: "Ken Follet",
  editorial: "DeBols!llo"
}
```

El problema me surge en si hago una web y quiero categorizar por ejemplo por editorial, para mostrar las diferentes editoriales tendría que consultar todos los documentos de libros y ver los valores diferentes para editorial.

Entonces se me ocurre hacer una colección con las editoriales y los libros hagan referencia a ella. Gano que para conseguir las diferentes editoriales es una consulta directa, pero por otro lado cada vez que muestro un libro tengo que hacer una consulta cruzada para obtener el valor de editorial (y tengo pensando categorizar por 8 campos diferentes lo que serían mas consultas diferentes por cada libro).

La otra idea que se me ocurre es no usar referencias, pero aún así crear la colección de editoriales. Mantengo la primera opción de no usar referencias que para este caso me parece lo más natural, pero evito tener que buscar a través de todos los libros los posibles valores de editoriales.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En mongodb es muy recomendado **embeber documentos** siempre que se pueda, especialmente en las relaciones 1-a-1.

**¿Por qué?** *Porqué no puede utilizar las operaciones atómicas de join como en las consultas SQL (aunque está no la principal razón).*

La principal razón es que cada operación de join (teóricamente) necesita una hard-seek que toma unos 20ms. Embeber los documentos sólo necesita 1ms de hard-seek.

Creo que el mejor esquema de db para tu problema es dejar el modelo original:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("52f602d787945c344bb4bda5"),
  titulo: "Los pilares de la Tierra",
  autor: "Ken Follet",
  editorial: "DeBols!llo"
}
```

Y consultar las diferentes editoriales con `db.libros.distinct( "editorial" )`

Y en caso de que necesites más información crear un documento dentro del documento, así:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("52f602d787945c344bb4bda5"),
  titulo: "Los pilares de la Tierra",
  autor: "Ken Follet",
  editorial: "DeBols!llo",
  ediciones: {
    1: 2005,
    2: 2012
    }
}
```

Por lo general, para embeber o referenciar puedes tener en cuenta estas pautas para tomar la decisión correcta:

**Embeber** es mejor para:

- Pequeños subdocumentos.
- Datos que no cambian regularmente.
- Cuando la consistencia final es aceptable.
- Documentos que crecen en pequeñas cantidades
- Datos que necesitarás a menudo para realizar una segunda consulta para obtener lecturas rápidas

**Referencias** es mejor para:

- Subdocumentos grandes
- Datos volátiles
- Cuando es necesaria la consistencia inmediata
- Documentos que crecen una gran cantidad
- Datos que a menudo excluye de los resultados
- Escrituras rápidas

**Fuentes:**

- [Documentación de mongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-one-relationships-between-documents/)
- [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247411/the-correct-way-of-storing-document-reference-in-one-to-one-relationship-in-mong)